# MapInfo - how to *publish* a WFS service?

Tags: wfs, mapinfo, mapxtreme

I seem to have my Pitney & Bowes technologies in a scramble.  We installed the demo version of MapInfo hoping to build a map and publish it as a WFS service.  We built the map but found no publish options.  We next tried MapXtreme and setup a 'Workspace' but there are again, no publish options.  I was expecting it to register assemblies in the GAC (e.g. MapInfo.CoreEngine) but it did not.

QUESTION: What P&B technology is used to publish a WFS service?

ANSWER: See page 400 on [this](http://reference.mapinfo.com/software/mapxtreme_windows/english/7_1_0/MapXtreme_DeveloperGuide.pdf) PDF

Comment: Windows Server with IIS http://reference.mapinfo.com/software/mapxtreme_windows/english/2005_6_5/MapXtreme2005_WFS_Server_Setup_Tutorial.pdf

Comment: I replaced MapInfo.Wfs.WfsHttpHandler with MapInfo.Wfs.Server.HttpHandler in those instructions and it worked.

Comment: could you turn your comment into an answer to help future users